# Kelp for very beginners

Tags: kelp

I have no coding experience at all but would like to use Kelp. I have managed to get it running on CMD.exe but have no clue what im doing. If anyone has a little spare time, could you please put out a video to show me and others like me How to get it going. Just a quick video, I'm sure i can learn my self once i have the basics!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a chance to look at the [walkthrough guides](https://github.com/stellar/kelp#walkthrough-guides)? It should help to get you started with three strategies: *buysell*, *sell*, and *balanced*.

I'm hoping that someone from the community can come up with tutorial videos on how to use [Kelp](https://github.com/stellar/kelp).

We just announced a GUI for Kelp which you can download from here: https://github.com/stellar/kelp/releases/tag/v1.9.0

Here’s the [announcement blog post for the GUI](https://link.medium.com/lXudBuogl6)

Here’s a [link to the tutorial video](https://kelpbot.io/video-gui-tutorial-first-bot/?tag=stack-overflow-kelp-beginners)

Comment: Anyone ever go and make a video on how to get this going. Would it work on an pi 2 something you could set and forget.

Comment: Nobody has made a video yet. Yes you can use it on a pi2, we have precompiled binaries for these at https://github.com/stellar/kelp/releases